# Arch Linux (LTS kernel) + ZFS 0.8.4: system locking up when trying to delete some files

Tags: linux, zfs

I'm hoping somebody might be able to help me troubleshoot here.  My home server is running Arch Linux, currently with the 5.4.60-1-lts kernel.  I currently use ZFS 0.8.4-1 (installed by zfs-dkms package) on this system.  My home folder actually resides on the ZFS pool, but the rest of the OS is just on a separate SSD.
The other day I opened Chromium browser and noticed that it was loading web pages either very very slowly, or not at all in most cases.  At the bottom left corner of the chromium window it was saying "Waiting for cache" all the time, and not loading pages.  I thought I would go and delete the .cache/chromium folder from my home directory.

I executed `sudo rm -r /home/justin/.cache/chromium` and at first I could hear the hard drives kick into action but the command never completed.  It just hung.  It did not lock up the whole system though, so I had a look at htop and saw the process for the command I executed was taking up 100% of one CPU core/thread.  I left it for probably a couple of hours and it just stayed like that.  Since then I've tried again a number of times and get the same result every time.  `kill -9` won't kill the hung process either, so the only get-out is to reboot the system.  Creating / deleting / moving files elsewhere in the filesystem seems fine (fingers crossed for no issues elsewhere), but it really does not like that chromium cache folder!

I captured some kernel log data while attempting to delete the folder ...

```
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 23s! [rm:1121909]
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: Modules linked in: vhost_net vhost tap fuse xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat ebtable_filter ebtables tun nfnetlink bridge stp llc nct6775 hwmon_vid eeepc_wmi asus_wmi battery nls_iso8859_1 sparse_keymap nls_cp437 rfkill vfat wmi_bmof mxm_wmi fat zfs(POE) snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_usb_audio edac_mce_amd snd_hda_intel zunicode(POE) snd_intel_nhlt zavl(POE) icp(POE) snd_usbmidi_lib kvm_amd snd_hda_codec snd_rawmidi kvm uvcvideo snd_seq_device videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common zcommon(POE) videodev znvpair(POE) crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul mc ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_core spl(OE) snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel zlua(POE) drm_kms_helper snd_timer crypto_simd ccp cryptd snd glue_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sp5100_tco k10temp sysimgblt pcspkr soundcore rng_core fb_sys_fops i2c_piix4 igb r8169 realtek libphy ipmi_devintf i2c_algo_bit dca ipmi_msghandler wmi
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  pinctrl_amd evdev mac_hid acpi_cpufreq nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nfsd nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_filter auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd drm grace sg sunrpc crypto_user agpgart ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 sd_mod ahci mpt3sas libahci raid_class libata crc32c_intel xhci_pci scsi_transport_sas ehci_pci xhci_hcd scsi_mod ehci_hcd vfio_pci irqbypass vfio_virqfd vfio_iommu_type1 vfio
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 1121909 Comm: rm Tainted: P           OE     5.4.60-1-lts #1
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/Pro WS X570-ACE, BIOS 2206 08/13/2020
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RIP: 0010:zap_leaf_lookup_closest+0xbc/0x170 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: Code: 00 00 4c 8b 70 18 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 8d 48 fb 44 89 c8 d3 e0 0f b7 ca 48 8d 0c 49 48 98 48 8d 04 88 49 8d 44 46 30 48 8b 48 10 <4c> 39 c1 76 bc 4c 39 d1 73 5a 8b 68 0c 44 0f b7 50 0a 44 89 db 4c
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa3c9ed2e7bc0 EFLAGS: 00000216 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RAX: ffff9598004cc430 RBX: 0000000000000004 RCX: 0001000000000000
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa3c9ed2e7bf0 RDI: ffff95aa9b195a00
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RBP: 00000000fcb76346 R08: 1380000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: R10: 7d77d659f91561db R11: 0000000000000004 R12: ffffa3c9ed2e7c06
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9598004cc000 R15: ffffa3c9ed2e7d38
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: FS:  00007fba662735c0(0000) GS:ffff95ac2e980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: CR2: 0000562deb863088 CR3: 0000000c6668e000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  fzap_cursor_retrieve+0x103/0x340 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  zap_cursor_retrieve+0x16c/0x300 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  zfs_readdir+0x147/0x420 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  zpl_iterate+0x4c/0x70 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  iterate_dir+0x143/0x1a0
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  ksys_getdents64+0x91/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  ? __ia32_compat_sys_getdents+0x130/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  __x64_sys_getdents64+0x16/0x20
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x49/0x90
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fba66171a8b
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: Code: eb b7 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 81 fa ff ff ff 7f b8 ff ff ff 7f 48 0f 47 d0 b8 d9 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 05 c3 0f 1f 40 00 48 8b 15 b1 93 0f 00 f7 d8
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc4472b468 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000d9
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562deb7e1980 RCX: 00007fba66171a8b
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RDX: 0000000000008000 RSI: 0000562deb7e19b0 RDI: 0000000000000003
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: RBP: 0000562deb7e19b0 R08: 0000000000008028 R09: 00007fba6626ba60
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: R10: 0000000000000150 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffffffffffffff88
Aug 26 22:16:00 IXTREME kernel: R13: 0000562deb7e1984 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000562deb7e9980
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 23s! [rm:1121909]
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: Modules linked in: vhost_net vhost tap fuse xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat ebtable_filter ebtables tun nfnetlink bridge stp llc nct6775 hwmon_vid eeepc_wmi asus_wmi battery nls_iso8859_1 sparse_keymap nls_cp437 rfkill vfat wmi_bmof mxm_wmi fat zfs(POE) snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_usb_audio edac_mce_amd snd_hda_intel zunicode(POE) snd_intel_nhlt zavl(POE) icp(POE) snd_usbmidi_lib kvm_amd snd_hda_codec snd_rawmidi kvm uvcvideo snd_seq_device videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common zcommon(POE) videodev znvpair(POE) crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul mc ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_core spl(OE) snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel zlua(POE) drm_kms_helper snd_timer crypto_simd ccp cryptd snd glue_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sp5100_tco k10temp sysimgblt pcspkr soundcore rng_core fb_sys_fops i2c_piix4 igb r8169 realtek libphy ipmi_devintf i2c_algo_bit dca ipmi_msghandler wmi
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  pinctrl_amd evdev mac_hid acpi_cpufreq nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nfsd nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_filter auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd drm grace sg sunrpc crypto_user agpgart ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 sd_mod ahci mpt3sas libahci raid_class libata crc32c_intel xhci_pci scsi_transport_sas ehci_pci xhci_hcd scsi_mod ehci_hcd vfio_pci irqbypass vfio_virqfd vfio_iommu_type1 vfio
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 1121909 Comm: rm Tainted: P           OEL    5.4.60-1-lts #1
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/Pro WS X570-ACE, BIOS 2206 08/13/2020
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RIP: 0010:zap_leaf_lookup_closest+0x83/0x170 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: Code: c2 ff ff ff ff 41 b9 01 00 00 00 4c 8d 66 16 41 0f b7 c3 41 0f b7 54 46 30 66 83 fa ff 75 20 e9 89 00 00 00 0f 84 b5 00 00 00 <0f> b7 50 02 66 83 fa ff 74 79 48 8b 87 d8 00 00 00 4c 8b 70 18 8b
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa3c9ed2e7bc0 EFLAGS: 00000287 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RAX: ffff9598004cc430 RBX: 0000000000000004 RCX: 0001000000000000
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa3c9ed2e7bf0 RDI: ffff95aa9b195a00
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RBP: 00000000fcb76346 R08: 1380000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: R10: 7d77d659f91561db R11: 0000000000000004 R12: ffffa3c9ed2e7c06
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9598004cc000 R15: ffffa3c9ed2e7d38
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: FS:  00007fba662735c0(0000) GS:ffff95ac2e980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: CR2: 0000562deb863088 CR3: 0000000c6668e000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  fzap_cursor_retrieve+0x103/0x340 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  zap_cursor_retrieve+0x16c/0x300 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  zfs_readdir+0x147/0x420 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  zpl_iterate+0x4c/0x70 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  iterate_dir+0x143/0x1a0
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  ksys_getdents64+0x91/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  ? __ia32_compat_sys_getdents+0x130/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  __x64_sys_getdents64+0x16/0x20
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x49/0x90
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fba66171a8b
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: Code: eb b7 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 81 fa ff ff ff 7f b8 ff ff ff 7f 48 0f 47 d0 b8 d9 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 05 c3 0f 1f 40 00 48 8b 15 b1 93 0f 00 f7 d8
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc4472b468 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000d9
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562deb7e1980 RCX: 00007fba66171a8b
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RDX: 0000000000008000 RSI: 0000562deb7e19b0 RDI: 0000000000000003
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: RBP: 0000562deb7e19b0 R08: 0000000000008028 R09: 00007fba6626ba60
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: R10: 0000000000000150 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffffffffffffff88
Aug 26 22:16:28 IXTREME kernel: R13: 0000562deb7e1984 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000562deb7e9980
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: rcu:         6-....: (6000 ticks this GP) idle=4c2/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=534040/534040 fqs=2798 
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:         (t=6000 jiffies g=1811881 q=109219)
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: NMI backtrace for cpu 6
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 1121909 Comm: rm Tainted: P           OEL    5.4.60-1-lts #1
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/Pro WS X570-ACE, BIOS 2206 08/13/2020
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  <IRQ>
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  dump_stack+0x64/0x88
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  nmi_cpu_backtrace.cold+0x14/0x53
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  ? lapic_can_unplug_cpu.cold+0x3e/0x3e
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xd5/0xd7
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x90/0xbe
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  rcu_sched_clock_irq.cold+0x1b3/0x3ad
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  update_process_times+0x5b/0x90
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  tick_sched_handle+0x22/0x60
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  tick_sched_timer+0x51/0xb0
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  ? can_stop_idle_tick+0x90/0x90
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x128/0x2a0
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  hrtimer_interrupt+0x10e/0x280
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x6e/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  </IRQ>
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RIP: 0010:zap_leaf_lookup_closest+0xb8/0x170 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: Code: 8b 87 d8 00 00 00 4c 8b 70 18 8b 87 d0 00 00 00 8d 48 fb 44 89 c8 d3 e0 0f b7 ca 48 8d 0c 49 48 98 48 8d 04 88 49 8d 44 46 30 <48> 8b 48 10 4c 39 c1 76 bc 4c 39 d1 73 5a 8b 68 0c 44 0f b7 50 0a
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa3c9ed2e7bc0 EFLAGS: 00000216 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RAX: ffff9598004cc430 RBX: 0000000000000004 RCX: 0000000000000000
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa3c9ed2e7bf0 RDI: ffff95aa9b195a00
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RBP: 00000000fcb76346 R08: 1380000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: R10: 7d77d659f91561db R11: 0000000000000004 R12: ffffa3c9ed2e7c06
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9598004cc000 R15: ffffa3c9ed2e7d38
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  fzap_cursor_retrieve+0x103/0x340 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  zap_cursor_retrieve+0x16c/0x300 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  zfs_readdir+0x147/0x420 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  zpl_iterate+0x4c/0x70 [zfs]
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  iterate_dir+0x143/0x1a0
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  ksys_getdents64+0x91/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  ? __ia32_compat_sys_getdents+0x130/0x130
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  __x64_sys_getdents64+0x16/0x20
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x49/0x90
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fba66171a8b
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: Code: eb b7 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 81 fa ff ff ff 7f b8 ff ff ff 7f 48 0f 47 d0 b8 d9 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 05 c3 0f 1f 40 00 48 8b 15 b1 93 0f 00 f7 d8
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc4472b468 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000d9
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562deb7e1980 RCX: 00007fba66171a8b
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RDX: 0000000000008000 RSI: 0000562deb7e19b0 RDI: 0000000000000003
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: RBP: 0000562deb7e19b0 R08: 0000000000008028 R09: 00007fba6626ba60
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: R10: 0000000000000150 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: ffffffffffffff88
Aug 26 22:16:34 IXTREME kernel: R13: 0000562deb7e1984 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000562deb7e9980
```

I see ZFS being mentioned there in a few places, so I'm assuming ZFS has been upset by something.  The version of ZFS that I have installed has not changed for some time.  I was working fine (although it's possible that this issue has gone unnoticed for a long time!).  There have been a few updates to the LTS kernel over the last couple of months ...

My hardware is a fairly new system which I built maybe 2 months ago:
Motherboard:  ASUS Pro WS x570-ACE
CPU:  AMD Ryzen 7 3800x
Memory:  Corsair Vengeance LPX 3200MHz 128GB total

I tested the RAM with MemTest86 (took AGES), and that passed with no errors.

So I'm at a bit of a loss as to what could cause this.  Could data corruption cause a rm process, or the ZFS module, to hang like this?

Here's the really weird part:  The ZFS pool in this system is replicated over to a backup machine once a day.  The backup machine runs FreeNAS.  I ssh'ed into that machine today and tried to delete the same .cache folder and it cause FreeNAS (or ZFS) to hang there as well.  I only tried that once though and I have no log data to share from that test.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers - Justin

Comment: I guess you'd get better help here: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues Edit: looks like you've already done that: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10825